# Proof by Induction help Prove that $9\mid4^{3n}-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am a bit stuck on this problem I got this far:

Base Case: $P(0) = 4^0-1=0$ thus it is apprarent $9\mid0$

Inductive Hypothesis: $P(k): 9\mid(4^{3k}-1)$ which means
$9q = 4^{3k}-1$  for some $q $

Then I  want to show $P(k+1)$ by considering

$$4^{3k+1}-1 = 4\times4^{3k}-1 = 4\times4^{3k}-1 -3+3 = 
 4\times4^{3k}-4+3 = 4(4^{3k}-1)+3$$    then by the assumption

$=4(9q)+3 = 36q +3$

I am really stuck, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've made a simple mistake, it should be $P(k+1)=4^{3(k+1)}-1=4^3 \cdot 4^{3k}-1=4^3 \cdot (9q+1)-1=4^3 \cdot 9q + 63=9 \cdot (4^3q+7)$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use induction to prove this.

$$4^{3n} - 1 = (4^3)^n - 1 = 64^n - 1 \equiv 1^n - 1 \pmod9$$
And $1^n - 1 = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Hence, $9 \space | \space 4^{3n} - 1$ for all $n \ge 0$.